# one-time key, zero IV in stream cipher (e.g. AES-CTR)

Tags: aes, initialization-vector, ctr

Say I am using a random key to construct a stream cipher with, say, AES in CTR mode, which will never be used to encrypt more than one data stream. Is there any advantage, no matter how small, to using a random IV instead of an IV of zero? I repeat, the key will never be used twice.